# Create custom wordlist

Tags: linux, ocr, spell-checking

I want to create a custom list of (scientific) words for purposes like spell checking and OCR based on my collection of scientific papers in pdf format. Using `pdftotext` I can easily create a text file which contains the wanted words for my scientific field. However the file will be polluted with

- words which are not specific for science (and which would also be contained in a common dictionary)
- words which result from improper conversion of e.g. formulas (including words which include special characters etc.)

I want to get rid of the later by requiring that individual words have a minimum length, contain no special characters and appear several times in the list. Secondly I want to get rid of the former by comparing with a second word list. My questions:

Does this sound like a good plan to you? Are there existing tools for this task? How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select words of at least 4 characters found at least 5 times and not found in /usr/share/dict/words in the PDF files in the current directory.

```
 find . -name '*.pdf' -exec pdftotext {} - \; |
   tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '[\n*]' |
   tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
   grep -E '.{4}' |
   sort |
   uniq -c |
   awk '$1 > 4 {print $2}' |
   comm -23 - <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < /usr/share/dict/words|sort -u)
```

You need a shell with support for process substitution (`ksh`, `zsh` or `bash`).

If you're going to use `perl` anyway, you can also do the whole thing in `perl`:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec pdftotext {} - \; |
  perl '-Mopen ":locale"' -nle '
     s/^\S+//;s/\S+$//;y/ \t/ /s;
     next unless length > 40;
     $w{lc$_}++ for /[[:alpha:]]{4,}/g;
     END{open W,"</usr/share/dict/words";
     while(<W>){chomp;delete $w{lc$_}};
     print for grep {$w{$_}>4} keys %w}'
```

Comment: I made good experience with this one. However I find some words in the result which are incomplete or drawn together. I think that some of this polution may come from words in the beginning or end of the lines, since they are often broken in the pdf files. I know how I would remove them in perl, but how would I do it in awk, which you use anyway?

Comment: @highsciguy, does `pdftotext -raw` make any difference? You can always use `perl -pe` to insert whatever perl processing you want to do. If you give some sample of the problematic output in your question, maybe we can assist.

Comment: I added a line `perl -lne '$_=~s/^[^\s]+\s+//; $_=~s/\s+[^\s]+$//; $_=~s/\s{2,}/ /g; if(length($_) > 40){ print $_; }' |` after the initial `pdftotext` which seems to clean many corrupted words. For instance I found that words with umlauts such as 'Jürgen' are sometimes broken in the pdftotext output as 'J"\nurgen'. 'urgen' is then added to the word list if not I filter it by removing first and last words as with this perl line. The man page of `pdftotext` recommends not to use the `-raw` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a very typical plan.  I would use shell scripts to do this.  You're not dealing with outrageously large quantities of text, so performance should be adequate, and shell scripts are easy to write and re-run.  My first cut would be a script like this:

```
pdf2text files |
tr -cs '[A-Za-z]' '\n' |  
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' |
awk '{ if (length > 6) {print $1;}}' |
fgrep -v -f /usr/share/groff/current/eign |
sort | 
uniq -c |
awk '{print $2, $1}' |
sort -nr +1 -2 |
head -20
```

That will get you the 20 most frequent words lf length greater than 6.

You can add steps, take out steps, adjust parameters to see what you get.

The `fgrep` step is the only odd one, and requires that [GNU troff](http://www.gnu.org/software/groff/) be installed. The file /usr/share/groff/current/eign is something like the 100 highest frequency words in english.  The "-v" flag only passes words that don't appear in the "eign" file, so it's using "eign" as a stop list.  If you don't like what GNU troff as as common words, you can make your own and use that file in the `fgrep` step.

Comment: Amazing how close our solutions are  (I swear I didn't read yours before coming up with mine). A few issues with yours: that's the non-standard SysV `tr` syntax so in most implementations that would include the `[` and `]` characters. With `fgrep`, you're matching substrings (also not that `comm` on sorted files is going to be a lot more efficient). That's also the old non-standard syntax for `sort` and `head`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the non-standard flags. As something of a dinosaur, I feel more familiar with them.