# search and replace over multiple files, including grammatical cases, plurals etc

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

There is a software documentation (written in Sphinx) consisting of a significant number of files, and I want to create a glossary.

This means I have a list of terms for which a glossary entry exists and want to replace each mention of each term by a link to the glossary. Of course, in the main documentation, these terms can occur in plurals, genitive, within a hyphenated longer term etc. The command by which I want to replace them should both include the term in its uninflected form and the text (plural etc.) that is supposed to appear in the main documentation's text.

What is an appropriate tool to do this semi-automatically, one that ideally has understanding of English cases built in?

Comment: This is... not trivial. [This post and its answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145462/22222) highlight some of the complications. It isn't about English, but many of the issues will be the same.